# why does the for loop not continue

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

i have the following sniped Code where i want to remove all '0' from the Array p4. This Array will be put into an arraylist amountOfColorPoints. The for Loop should be working until the end of the size of the list but it is not executing anymore after the first '0' was removed as i can see on the console. What is the Problem? Could please someone help me?

```
int[] p4={0,0,4};

ArrayList<Integer> amountOfColorPoints = new ArrayList<>();
```

.
.
.

```
for(int p=0; p<amountOfColorPoints.size(); p++) {
                if (amountOfColorPoints.get(p) == 0)
                    amountOfColorPoints.remove(p);}
```

Comment: You need an `Iterator`

Comment: Think about what you are doing, you first remove the first 0 leaving you collection as `{0,4}`, then you check if the second value is 0, it isn't it's 4 and your loop terminates.

Comment: there's a few issues, but one of the more important ones here is that you are both iterating *and* modifying the list at the same time, and that's a guaranteed bug right there. Unless you're running through your list backwards, which you're not. As an exercise, take some pen and paper, and for your three element array, write out what happens to your position, and your array, at each step of this code. This'll take you maybe a minute, but is a valuable exercise.

Answer (score 3):

The safe way to remove elements from a collection (while iterating it) is with [`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) as the Javadoc notes

> The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.

Something like,

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = amountOfColorPoints.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    if (iter.next() == 0) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On every iteration of the loop the size of the array is recalculated. So, when you remove the element on position 0, the array size becomes 2, the second 0 shifts to position 0, but p is already 1, so you skip the second 0.

Correct code:

```
   Iterator<Integer> iter = amountOfColorPoints.iterator();
   while (iter.hasNext()) {
     if (iter.next() == 0) {
       iter.remove();
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when you remove an element, all remaining elements are shuffled to the left to fill the gap, so the next element after removal will be the *same* index, but you still increment the index.

To make you code work, decrement the index:

```
for(int p=0; p<amountOfColorPoints.size(); p++) {
    if (amountOfColorPoints.get(p) == 0)
        amountOfColorPoints.remove(p--); // decrement 
}
```

A better approach is to use an `Iterator`, which allows you to remove the current element (with having to worry about indexes).